# GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable crash on some devices

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

We got some bug report from some Sony Xperia devices.
We can confirm that we already declaration this meta-data with

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"     android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />.
```

But some devices will got an error `"com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesMissingManifestValueException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />".`

How can we fix this crash?

Stack trace log:
`Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application : com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesMissingManifestValueException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`
`at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6853)`
`at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:256)`
`at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2112)`
`at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)`
`at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)`
`at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)`
`at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7984)`
`at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke`
`at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:583)`
`at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1026)`
`Caused by com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesMissingManifestValueException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`
`at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable`
`at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailabilityLight.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable`
`at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.ensurePlayServicesAvailable`
`at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailabilityLight.verifyGooglePlayServicesIsAvailable`
`at com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded`
`at App.onCreate (App.java)`
`at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1212)`
`at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6848)`

It only happens on some Sony Xperia devices. I really don't know why